# What is the limit of the following term?

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

Find the limit of the following term:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{2x-3}-\sqrt{ax+b},$$

while $a\in\mathbb{R}^+,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Please, I need help!!!

Comment: Tell us what you already know to help us better help you.  Do you know what a limit is?  Do you know what $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{2x-3}$ is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sqrt{2x-3}-\sqrt{ax+b} =  \dfrac{(\sqrt{2x-3} - \sqrt{ax+b})(\sqrt{2x+3} + \sqrt{ax+b})}{\sqrt{2x-3} + \sqrt{ax+b}} =\frac{(2x-3)-(ax+b)}{\sqrt{2x-3} + \sqrt{ax+b}}$$

$$= \frac{(2-a)x-(3+b)}{\sqrt{2x-3}+\sqrt{ax+b}}$$

Can you take the limit now? The degree of the numerator exceeds that of the denominator: try dividing numerator and denominator by $\sqrt x$. Then use the fact that given $a>0$, $2-a>0$ provided $0\leq a \lt 2$, $2-a = 0$ when $a=2$, and $2-a \lt 0$ when $a>2$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Multiply and divide by the conjugate.

Comment: ...and then see for what values of $a$ this converges. What about $b$, does its value matter?

Comment: @SimonS Nope. In fact I left that to the OP.

Comment: My comment was intended as an additional hint for the OPer (and not as a correction for you or anything else negative).

Comment: *OPer;  @SimonS Oh, I see. I thought you were suggesting an improvement, so I wanted to clarify my intention. No problem anyway.